# How can i skip the download from Boundless? (maven)

Tags: java, maven

My project might have had a depenendency on boundless before, but it is nowhere in my code anymore. How can I skip this time consuming step? On what locations do I have to look?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.me.mylibrary >-------------------
[INFO] Building MyLibrary 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from boundless: https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/eclipse/emf/org.eclipse.emf.common/maven-metadata.xml
```

Comment: There has to be a `<repository>` entry somewhere in your `pom.xml` (or maybe your `settings.xml`) that mentions it. If you no longer need any dependencies from that repository, simply remove that entry.

Comment: Note that `boundless` is a repository so your pom.xml or settings.xml is probably still refering to it. Just remove that repo - or use different profiles if it's in your `settings.xml` and you might need it in another project.

Comment: I couldn't find anything from boundless in my `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`. I think I have a dependency that relies on boundless, is that possible? (not via parent-pom, but via other libraries)

Comment: But is there a way to not try to download things from boundless on each `compile`? Some skip argument or so? I know `-o` but I'm in the process of upgrading dependencies so I need that.

Comment: Have a look at the output of `mvn help:effective-pom`. Perhaps it's coming from your parent pom.

Comment: OK, I guess I still have an old dependency. Is it possible to block the download-process for specific repositories?

Comment: @tgdavies effective-pom didn't show up results. But if i `rgrep` throug my m2 repositories I find dependencies with boundless references. Probably I'm using these in some way.

Comment: I'm trying to get things working with a mirror in settings.xml now..